# Is $x^8+1$ irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> How to decide if $f(x)=x^8+1$ is irreducible or not over the following fields:
>
> 1. $F=\mathbb R$
> 2. $F=\mathbb Q$.

I can't use Eisenstein's criterion. So the only possibility is computing the complex 8th-roots of -1?

Comment: Why can't you use Eisenstein's criterion?

Comment: Because I need a prime, which divides 1, correct? And there is no prime which divides 1

Comment: It wasn't clear to me whether you couldn't use because you're not allowed to or because of the reason you just gave. There's a way to fix the problem you mentioned. See Sergio's answer.

Comment: Alright :) I got it now, thanks to everyone!

Comment: One question: Is $x^3-13$ irreducible in $\mathbb R$?. On the one hand is should be reducible because there exists a root in $\mathbb R$ for sure. On the other hand eisenstein's criterion yields that it is irreducible, because p=13, divides 13 but not 1...so whats the answer here?

Comment: Eisenstein's criterion is talking about $\mathbb{Q}$, not $\mathbb{R}$. Btw, don't forget to choose the best answer).

Comment: Reducibility is a field dependent concept. Eisenstein tells you $x^3-13$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$, it asserts nothing about the polynomial's irreducibility over the reals. As you've pointed out, it is reducible over the reals.

Comment: Thanks for the answers again. I did not realize that the theorem works only for $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Every polynomial of degree three or more, with real coefficients, can be factored over $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$X^{8}+1$ is indeed irreducible in $\mathbb Q[X]$: it is the $16$-th cyclotomic polynomial. A possible elementary way to prove this is to consider $(X+1)^{8}+1$, which is irreducible iff $X^{8}+1$ is. All the coefficients of $(X+1)^{8}+1$ are even except the first one, and the last coefficient is $2$, so Eisenstein criterion applies.

For $\mathbb{R}[X]$ Jihad already gave you an answer.

Answer (score 7):

Irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ have degree $\leq 2$ since you can find roots over $\mathbb{C}$ and then multiply conjugated terms.

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

1. Try seeing if you can find a factorization of $x^4 + 1$ of the form $(x^2 + ax + b)(x^2 + cx + d)$ for suitable real constants $a, b, c, d$.  Can you then use this to find a factorization of $x^8 + 1$?

Comment: Nice trick! thank you

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** [Completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square), we have $x^8+1=\Big(x^4\Big)^2+1^2=\Big(x^4+1\Big)^2-2x^4.~$ Can you take it from here ? :-)

Answer (score 1):

We can start with something similar.

Factor $x^4 + 4$:

$x^4 + 4x^2 + 4 - 4x^2$

$(x^2+2)^2 - (2x)^2$

$(x^2+2-2x)(x^2+2+2x)$

$\boxed{x^4 + 4 = (x^2-2x+2)(x^2+2x+2)}$

We could use the same method to factor $x^4+1$:

$x^4 + 2x^2 + 1 - 2x^2$

$(x^2+1)^2 - (\sqrt{2}x)^2$

$(x^2+1-\sqrt{2}x)(x^2+1+\sqrt{2}x)$

$\boxed{x^4 + 1 = (x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1)(x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1)}$

Here's what I discovered:
$x^4 + y^4 = (x^2+y^2-\sqrt{2}xy)(x^2+y^2+\sqrt{2}xy)$

This shows that every sum of fourth powers can be factored. Now let's factor $x^8+1$:

$(x^2)^4 + 1^4$

$((x^2)^2+1-\sqrt{2}x^2)((x^2)^2+1+\sqrt{2}x^2)$

$\boxed{(x^4-\sqrt{2}x^2+1)(x^4+\sqrt{2}x^2+1)}$

Hope it helps!